# Difference between filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext and filterContext.HttpContext in ASP.NET MVC filters`?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

can someone tell me what is the difference between `filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext` and `filterContext.HttpContext` in ASP.NET MVC filters?

It seems `filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext` is not holding the `.Session` on every (child) request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**filterContext.RequestContext**

is a property of type `System.Web.Routing.RequestContext`. which Encapsulates information about an HTTP request that matches a defined route.The `RequestContext` class contains information about the HTTP request in the `HttpContext` property.It contains information about the route that matched the current request in the `RouteData` property.When you construct a URL from a route, you pass an instance of the `RequestContext` class to the `RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath` method.

**filterContext.HttpContext**

is a property of type `System.Web.HttpContextBase`. which Serves as the base class for classes that contain HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP request.The `HttpContextBase` class is an abstract class that contains the same members as the `HttpContext` class.The `HttpContextBase` class enables you to create derived classes that are like the `HttpContext` class, but that you can customize and that work outside the ASP.NET pipeline. When you perform unit testing, you typically use a derived class to implement members with customized behavior that fulfills the scenario you are testing. **Session is a property of HttpContextBase.**